# Converting strings to numerical values

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

[This image shows the dataframe I am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrRRe.png)

I want to do a few things:

1. Convert `player_positions` to the count of unique values. So T. Barkhuizen, for instance, can play as a RM, RWB or ST and so would have a value of 3
2. Convert `work_rate` to numerical values, with Low=1, Medium=2 and High=3 and sum the two values. With Barkhuizen as an example again, his `work_rate` value would be equal to 5 because he has High (3) and Medium (2)
3. If `player_traits` contains 'Injury Prone', convert to -1, otherwise convert to 1 (or possibly 0?)

Thank you in advance

Comment: @chitown88 I'd be very grateful for your advice again if you have the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
df['player_positions'] = df['player_positions'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
```

For your work rate you could define a function that converts the values and returns the sum (if I understand how your data works, anyway). Example:

```
def cnvWorkRate(rate):
    rates = rate.split('/')
    vals = {
        'High':3,
        'Medium':2,
        'Low':1
    }
    
    return sum([vals[r] for r in rates])
```

Comment: thanks so much for the `cnvWorkRate` function, it works perfectly

Comment: for `player_positions`, I ended up doing `df['positional_versatility'] = df['player_positions'].str.split(',')` and then `df['positional_versatility'] = df['player_positions'].str.split(',').str.len()`

Comment: any idea how to convert `player_traits` to a binary column depending on whether or not a player is Injury Prone?

Comment: You could use the same approach:
`df['player_traits'] = df['player_traits'].apply(lambda s: int('Injury Prone' in s))`

Comment: with that I get `TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable`, even though I know that `player_traits` is an `object`, not a `float64` 

Comment: @TomBomer Can you post the relevant chunk of your code?

Comment: don't worry I have now found a solution. if you'd like me to share the code please let me know

Comment: @TomBomer if I helped much, can you mark my answer as the accepted one? :)